# Site appears blocked in robots, but Google Search Console still says any tested URL is allowed?

Tags: google-search-console, search-engine-indexing, robots.txt

Working on a client's site, I noticed an error when trying to use a duplicate content checker tool. The tool stated that the home page was blocked by robots.txt.

In search console, I can see the robots.txt does indeed contain the lines:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

But when I test it, it says "Allowed" for any page I check.

Also worth noting that all pages in sitemap are indexed, no errors/conflicts reported. The only thing I can think of is that the above lines in the robots file are then followed by a link to the sitemap.

Does this then override the Disallow command?

Comment: If you don't mind, please post the whole content of the robots.txt (e.g. with altered URLs). Some other content might interfere with the disallow and render it invalid.

Answer (score 1):

A link to a sitemap file should not invalidate the Disallow command in the setup that you have described (specifically: if the directives occur in that order).

Things that I would look out for:

- Does the "Disallow" line follow immediately after the "User-agent" line? (invalid commands in this place might lead to the "Disallow" being ignored)
- Is there more than one "User-agent" block in the file? (might lead to Googlebot ignoring the "Disallow")
- If there is more other stuff inside the robots.txt file: might it otherwise interfere with the disallow?

On one occasion I have come across a robots.txt file that contained invisible unicode characters. As a result of this paths where not as they looked in the browser. Solution: run file through a text editor that is able to convert between different encodings, to get rid of the special characters.